# Multiple right margins in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pep8

I am learning Pycharm Community Edition 3.4 and I was wondering If it was possible to have a right a margin for comments and docstring only, additionally to the regular margin for the rest of the code.

I ask because I am trying to stick to the PEP8 guideline of 72 characters per comment and 79 for regular code. I am constantly changing the right margin between 72/79 to make sure everything is fine but I don't find that very efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a column counter at the bottom right of your PyCharm UI, you might be able to simply use that.

Answer (score 3):

This feature was [announced in September 2017](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99875#comment=27-2433505).

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> `Hard wrap at` and `Visual guides`.  For visual guides, you can enter multiple values separated by commas.

[image: Visual guides settings]
[image: Visual guides example]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible in Pycharm given its basic configuration (without some plugins). But I am afraid that even plugins for this feature does not exist for Pycharm. At least, I could not find it.

*In this question you may probably find something helpful:*
https://superuser.com/questions/703425/intellij-ide-how-to-add-one-or-more-margins.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet a feature of any of the Intellij platforms.

You can follow/vote for the ticket here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99875