# How can I make PyCharm's Fill Paragraph command override the default margin?

Tags: python, comments, pycharm, pep8

PyCharm has a great Fill Paragraph command, the only problem is that it wraps to the right margin setting. The problem with this is that it doesn't follow PEP8. I want to set my right margin to 79 to follow PEP8, but I want my comment blocks to be 72 characters, as PEP8 specifies. When I run the Fill Paragraph command I want it to wrap to 72 characters, not to 79. If it's not possible to do in PyCharm then I'll probably just not follow PEP8 this strictly; it's not worth taking the time to manually fix up the line length of comments in my opinion, 79 will have to do.

References:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125957/multiple-right-margins-in-pycharm, but no answer there.

Comment: Edit / Fill Paragraph

Comment: Yes definitely a duplicate. Thanks for showing me, sorry for the duplicate. Guess there's no answer to date, probably not supported by PyCharm.

Comment: The feature would be nice to have, normal lines and comments/docstings should be handled differently. May be, as a next step, visit pycharm's [issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY) and look if the feature-request exists, if not, feel free to create one. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found feature-request about it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15700 in PyCharm bug tracker. You need to vote for it to increase its priority and be notified about updates.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this plugin:

https://github.com/abrookins/WrapToColumn

This allows you to set a custom line-width for wrapping.
So setting that to 72 and running the wrapper on the docstring works quite nicely!